# Converting to pandas datetime data does not match format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, netcdf, python-xarray

I have a netcdf dataset and I want to convert the time to pandas datetime format.
The entries look like this:

```
<xarray.DataArray 'time' ()>
array(19810101.47916667)
Coordinates:
    time     float64 1.981e+07
Attributes:
    axis:           T
    calendar:       proleptic_gregorian
    standard_name:  time
    units:          day as %Y%m%d.%f
```

When I try to convert the data like this

```
pd.to_datetime(19810101.47916667,format='%Y%m%d.%f')
```

I get the error "time data '19810101' does not match format '%Y%m%d.%f' (match)".
I fail to undertand what exactly is going wrong here. Especially since this is exactly the format mentioned in the netcdf data (as you can see above).
Can someone tell me what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to make your date value a string as below:

```
pd.to_datetime("19810101.47916667",format='%Y%m%d.%f'
```

Comment: Oh you are right. Never had to do anythine like this before, so I totally missed it. Not quite sure why it is different to the other datasets, but I will gladly take it.